# Hexo - Same title under different categories changing permalink

Tags: hexo

I have a hexo setup that uses Permalink category/page. My question is that is there any way to use same titles under different categories? For example, I need A "Statistics" page under category "India" and "USA". When I'm trying to do this, hexo is generating a space (℅20) to the Permalink of the second category. Is there any way to generate the file without the change in Permalink?

Ps: it is important that I keep the title exactly same.